# Invalid binary when uploading to App Store

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I was using the following features before, I am not using it at the moment, so I removed it from `info.plist`, but I am having a problem when I upload the application. I don't want to add those features to `info.plist` because I don't use them anymore. What should I do?

> **ITMS-90683:** Missing Purpose String in Info.plist - Your app's code references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's Info.plist file should contain a NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your app needs the data. Starting Spring 2019, all apps submitted to the App Store that access user data are required to include a purpose string. If you're using external libraries or SDKs, they may reference APIs that require a purpose string. While your app might not use these APIs, a purpose string is still required. You can contact the developer of the library or SDK and request they release a version of their code that doesn't contain the APIs. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/protecting_the_user_s_privacy).
>
> **ITMS-90683**: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist - Your app's code references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's Info.plist file should contain a NSCameraUsageDescription key with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your app needs the data. Starting Spring 2019, all apps submitted to the App Store that access user data are required to include a purpose string. If you're using external libraries or SDKs, they may reference APIs that require a purpose string. While your app might not use these APIs, a purpose string is still required. You can contact the developer of the library or SDK and request they release a version of their code that doesn't contain the APIs.

Comment: "While your app might not use these APIs, a purpose string is still required" Pretty clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're seeing that warning, the App Store (by automatically looking through your compiled application) believes that you're using those features. Usually this means that code exists in your application that references these APIs. In this case, it's code that works with the camera and photo library. Even if you don't use those features any more, if the code in your compiled binary references those APIs, Apple will insist on those purposes being present in your `info.plist` (since they can't tell the difference between those features being present and used, or present and unused).

Your choices are:

- If you don't think those features will be coming back, remove the code that uses these APIs entirely from your app. You may also want to just temporarily not include the files by removing them from your app's build target.
- If this is too complex, and you're certain that these features aren't actually in use in your app any more, then fill out those parts of your `info.plist` with whatever messages you had previously, safe in the knowledge that no user will ever actually see them.

In summary, if you reference those APIs, even if you don't use them, you must have appropriate purpose strings in your app's `info.plist`.